# Kafka: Using multiple consumers to reduce consumer lag doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python, kafka-burrow

hi I have a Kafka cluster using 3 Brokers (EC2 instances)
and there is a topic with 100 partitions.

I wanted to observe how much a messages per second
a certain number of consumers can handle.

So I've sent messages by [20, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000] per second.
And for each message send rate I used [1, 10, 20, 30, ..., 100] consumers
with each consumer to work on a single ec2 instance.

I used kafka-python for making Producers and Consumers.
Burrow, telegraf, influxDB, Grafana was used to observe consumer lag by partition and total consumer lag.

I got the total consumer lag from the this http endpoint.
burrow endpoint: /v3/kafka/live/consumer/{consumer-group}/status

The result came out like the images.

[image: Pattern observed in grafana]

[image: Result of max lag observed]

Comment: Looks like the lag is decreasing. What is your question?

Comment: the lag in the image decreases because I stopped the producer
if I leave it the pattern in the image continues on and on
is this pattern of consumer lag normal?

Comment: That would largely depend if your consumer does auto or manual commit